# Encryption of sqlite db in java

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption

I am using SQLite JDBC driver from xerial project. What do we mean when we say encrypting the sqlite db ? I would like to know the best way to encrypt either the data in the db or the whole sqlite DB. For that, do I need to encrypt each field value and then write it in to DB or should I simply encrypt the .db file using Java ? What are the pros and cons and method generally used ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Deep

Answer (score 3):

try this http://sqlite-crypt.com/index.htm

Comment: Can this be used in Java ? What I understand is this is only for C/C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

There is an encryption library ([sqlite-crypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/)) available in C, but if you want to do it in Java, You could simply encrypt the database file like any other file. See this example of [file encryption/decryption in Java](http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS4B/Crypto/FileEncryptor.html).

You might also like to take a look at [SafeJDBC](http://safejdbc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

see [sqlite-jdbc-crypt](https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt) forked from [xerial/sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)

> This is not the original version from xerial.org. It is a fork of the
>   original. This version include and use
>   https://github.com/Willena/libsqlite3-wx-see as the native librairy.
>   So the output jar is equivalent to xerial's one. This one includes
>   some functionalities such as encryption and user authentication.
>   Thanks to https://github.com/utelle/wxsqlite3 project that added these
>   improvement, this library can now be updated in order to support these
>   new functionalities.